# I am trying to start ddev, but I am getting an error

Tags: command-line-interface, ddev

[Failed to start app-viewnit: container failed to become healthy: err=container 'web' exited, please use 'ddev logs -s web' to find out why it failed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y7s5t.png)

[cp: cannot create regular file '/home/mi6ka/./bash_aliases.example': Permission denied
cp: cannot create regular file '/home/mi6ka/./README.txt': Permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEFcA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like ddev cant create a file in your homedir. Did you check the output of `ddev logs -s web` ?

Comment: yes, the second photo shows the output of "ddev logs -s web"

Answer (score 0):

You assigned ownership of your own folder to a user and a group with the name "1000". That's certainly wrong.
See [the man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chown) for chown.